# Wiki with good support for page moves?

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

We use DokuWiki to manage our internal documentation but the page renames / moves are not supported very well (there is no built-in way other than messing with raw files manually and the third-party plugin 'pagemove' is no longer developed). Which is a pain.

I'm looking for an alternative which will be similarly simple as DokuWiki (must be filesystem-based) but handle the page renames/moves well. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will get a better chance of a good answer if you ask this kind of question on superuser.com

Comment: Maybe you meant serverfault? Anyway, there are quite a few wiki questions here on SO so I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [Comparison of wiki software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software) and sorting them by Data backend, there seem to be quite a few file system based wiki's. Skipping the webpages that are down or incomprehensible turns up the following viable candidates:

- [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinFeatures)
- [Twiki](http://twiki.org/)
- [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PmWikiFeatures) (after installing a plugin)
- [JSPWiki](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/JSPWikiFeatures)

In the end it's up to you to decide which of these best suits your needs & supports migrating your existing contents to the new wiki (no small feat), but at least it's a start.

Comment: Thanks Tim, MoinMoin doesn't look as pretty as DokuWiki but its features look good.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone whose search lands them on this page - you might also be interested in the plug-in that keeps links for moved and renamed pages in DokuWiki:
http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:move

Comment: plugin:move is great